# I need a help on how to create a table for each users as a user's contact list

Tags: django-rest-framework

Hi I am working on Django rest frame work. I need a help on how to create a table for each users as a user's contact list. This table needs to be created after user got registered himself.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a table for each user. What you need is a many to many relationship between each user and the contact table. 
You can read more about [many-to-many relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) in the docs

Answer (score 0):

In My Openion , You Should have Django Triggers,Signals and manyToMany Fields . Watch Django Official documentation You Could achieve Yourself.

Comment: hi guys thanks for your input i am checking, let me get back to you if i have any doubt.